# is it possible to know if we are already inside a iframe

Tags: selenium, iframe

In my application most of all the elements are inside `iframe`.

so my `POM (Page Object Model)` methods will start with switching to `frame` and then the code for performing actions..am able to perform action by switching to frame.

below is an example of my code:

```
public void method 1()
{
  driver.switchTo().frame(0);
  // code to perform actions....
  method 2();
  driver.switchTo().defaultcontent();
}

public void method 2()
{
  driver.switchTo().frame(0);
  // code to perform actions....
}
```

As per above example, the 2nd method is called from 1st method

The `driver` will get into frame from method 1, when the method 2 is called again it tried to switch to frame 0, as i hardcoded the frame index, i thought it will work fine (i.e even driver is on same frame), but its giving error as

> "No such frame exception."

is it possible to know the current `frame`? like if we know the frame then i can add a condition and decide to switch or not to switch, please guide.

Comment: Can you please provide the html code for this???

Comment: What does method1 and method2 do? Is there some reason method2 can't be combined with method1?

Comment: You can put `driver.switchTo().defaultcontent();` inside method 2 as well. So whenever you are switching to frame call  `driver.switchTo().defaultcontent();`

Comment: Switching to default content also a solution for my problem.Thank you madhan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by creating a `global` `variable` for current switched `frame` like below approach :-

```
String currentFrame = null;
//make this currentFrame as global variable


public void switchToFrame(String frame) {

 if ((null != frame) && (!"".equals(frame))) {
     if (!frame.equals(currentFrame)) {
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
        currentFrame = frame;
     }
 } else {
    currentFrame = "";
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
 }
}
```

Now you can use it in your methods as below :-

```
public void method 1()
{
  switchToFrame("your frame id or name"); //pass null if you want to switch to default
  // code to perform actions....
  method 2();
}

public void method 2()
{
  switchToFrame("your frame id or name"); //pass null if you want to switch to default
  // code to perform actions....
}
```

**Note :** - If you does not want yo create a `global` `variable` to know about current frame, you can also use `JavascriptExecutor` to know about current frame as below :-

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String currentFrame = jsExecutor.executeScript("return self.name");
```

Hope it will help you...:)

Comment: Thanks a lot Saurabh, looks like this solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could search for the frame again and if you find it, you know you aren't already in the frame.

I would try to simplify the methods so that they don't rely on each other as much as possible.